# What are the health impacts of soy lecithin?

Tags: nutrition

I accidentally bought organic soy lecithin granules thinking it was soy granules. I did some research and found that the recommended intake is two spoons a day for an adult.

I could not find any useful information as to why this quantity is recommended.

What are the health impacts of eating more than two spoons of soy lecithin per day? Can I safely consume more than this quantity, e.g. because I like the taste?